# How to route all routes through router.js file with Express?

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I have app.js file where I route /api routes to api.js file:

```
const api = require("./src/rest/api")
......
app.use("/api", api)
```

I am planning to to do all routing in router.js file, so router.js file would look like this:

```
app.all("/api", api)
app.all("/status", status)
```

How can I achieve this? I tried to use app.use("/", router) in app.js file but when I receive request in router.js file, the path doesn't anymore exist.

Comment: It is not quite clear what u want to achieve?

Comment: Does Express have a feature which I could use to tell it I have a router.js and I want add routes there? Is there a way I can route /api calls to api router using router.js file?

Comment: please provide the desired full routes. The example above is not understandable at all. Because is is not clear what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*main.js*

```js
const router = require('router.js')

app.use('/api', router)
```

*router.js*

```js
const router = express.Router()

// path: /api/status
router.get('/status', (req, res, next)=>{
 // do something here
}) 

module.exports = router
```